# Process of database backup in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I am using SQL server 2012. I want to take hourly database backup. I can do it using sql scheduling. but what is backup process.which type should i use for backup.
I am trying this, first full backup then differential backup, and while restoring .first restore full backup then differential.

Comment: have you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/create-a-full-database-backup-sql-server)?

Comment: You don't even know backup types but already know that you want to do it hourly?

Comment: Why don't use any third party tool to do it. For example, you can use https://sqlbackupandftp.com/ or https://sqlbak.com We have a good experience with SQLBackupAndFTP.

Answer (score -1):

Full backup weekly
Diff backup daily
Transaction log backup hourly

When you restore
Last Full backup first
Last differential backup
All transaction log backups after last diff backup

Comment: Thanks Irfan for understanding my Question. Should i create different backup files or overwrite the same file.

Comment: It depends on your retention policy. Also create a maintenance task to delete older files. I would suggest to use Ola hallengren scripts for backups.https://ola.hallengren.com

Comment: i have created full backup then differential backup.there are multiple differential backup file.first  I have restore full backup file.Now problem with remaining file of differetial backup. should i restore latest differetial backup file ?